# Asynchronous communication between Javascript and Phonegap Plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

So, everybody knows that we make a Class extending `CordovaPlugin` and override the  `execute()` and then creates a bridge between the JS and native Java (for Android). Further we use `PluginResult` to return the result back to the JS.

So, all of this happens when there is a request fired from the JS to the Java Plugin. My question is, **how to send a result back to JS** (and therefore to HTML) **asynchronously ?**

I don't know if the word **asynchronous** is right here. The thing is I want to send something back to the JS out of the blue (say, when wifi becomes enable/disable).

I have already researched on this but haven't got anything which suits to my case.

The thing I've tried is -

- Created a `BroadcastReceiver` listening to the `WiFi` events using the `WifiManager` class.

  Registered the receiver.

  And finally, popping a `Toast` when `WiFi` is enabled/disabled, and sending the result using  `CallbackContext`
  `callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "Wifi 
  Connected"))` and for disconnected with a different message.

**MyPlugin.java**

```
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;

...

public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
private WifiReceiver wifiBroadcastReceiver = null;
private CallbackContext callbackContext = null;

...

    public MyPlugin() {     
        wifiBroadcastReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
    ...
    }
    ...
    public boolean execute(String action, final JSONArray args,
            final CallbackContext callbackId) throws JSONException {
        IntentFilter wifiFilter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
        cordova.getActivity().registerReceiver(wifiBroadcastReceiver, wifiFilter);
        this.callbackContext = callbackId;

    ...
    }
    public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false)) {
                    Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity(), "Wifi Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "Wifi Connected"));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity(), "Wifi Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "Wifi Disconnected"));
                }
            }           
        }

}
```

The `Toast` pops but the `PluginResult` isn't sent to the JS.

---

**PS :** Listening to WiFi events isn't my actual problem, I want to replicate the `Android Bluetooth Chat` app in Phonegap. So, it has to be asynchronous in nature.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are almost there but you need to setKeepCallback to true on your PluginResult. If you don't the subsequent results from the Java side will not have a callback on the JavaScript side. The best example of this type of coding is the Network plugin in Cordova core. Here is a link to the source:

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-plugin-network-information.git;a=blob;f=src/android/NetworkManager.java;h=e2ac500ccc885db641d5df6dab8eae23026a5828;hb=HEAD

So you should update your code to:

```
public boolean execute(String action, final JSONArray args,
        final CallbackContext callbackId) throws JSONException {
    IntentFilter wifiFilter = new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
    cordova.getActivity().registerReceiver(wifiBroadcastReceiver,
            wifiFilter);
    this.callbackContext = callbackId;
    PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
    result.setKeepCallback(true);
    this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
    return true;
}

public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
            PluginResult result;
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                    WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false)) {
                Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity(), "Wifi Connected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK,
                        "Wifi Connected");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity(), "Wifi Disconnected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR,
                        "Wifi Disconnected");
            }

            result.setKeepCallback(false);
            if (callbackContext != null) {
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
                callbackContext = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll just check it out.

Comment: I implemented this in my original Bluetooth Chat app. JS does receive the result but it is in the form of `Second Callback`. And how did I notice it? It reflects in the Logcat that 

`W/CordovaPlugin(6976): Attempted to send a second callback for ID: BluetoothPlugin1980589494<BR>W/CordovaPlugin(6976): Result was: "Hello"`.  
So, now the question is, **How to handle these Second Callbacks** in JS or in HTML?

Comment: Please reply Simon, i'm desperately waiting.

Comment: Hey Simon, you must be pretty busy? That's why you are not replying. I hope that everything is okay. 

Can you suggest me using `sendJavascript()` to send back the result back to Javascript, I didn't find any proper documentation for this method. Please tell me what its implications could be instead of using the callback.

Comment: The solution you suggested was good if there is only one `exec` call from Javascript to Java Plugin's `execute()`. My problem is that, I have many `exec` calls from Javascript to Java, so, I am wondering that in which exec call's `callback` I will handle those `Second Callbacks`. That was the reason I switched to `sendJavascript()` so that I may call a Javascript function whenever I want [say, when a new chat msg arrived]. This is my stuff and I am stuck on it. And no one's replying. What should I use, `second callback` or `sendJavascript()`?

Comment: In the javascript/html file how do you register this event?

Comment: But if callbackContext changes to null at the end and the WiFi state changes, how will the sendPluginResult method will be called?

Answer (score 13):

Answer to 'second callback' warning...

The Cordova source-code which triggers this warning can be found on line 57 here:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CallbackContext.java

Thus - warning is caused because your CallbackContext object has 'finished=true'.

Most likely cause of this is you called: `callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);`

Without first calling: `pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);`

If not... most likely you are **unintentionally caching the CallbackContext object.**

Your execute() function should assign CallbackContext each time it is called. See lines 125-127 in the [code Simon linked to](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-plugin-network-information.git;a=blob;f=src/android/NetworkManager.java;h=e2ac500ccc885db641d5df6dab8eae23026a5828;hb=HEAD):

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {

if (action.equals("getConnectionInfo")) {`

this.connectionCallbackContext = callbackContext;

...
```

The proper sequence of events in full:

1. Make initial call to plugin.
2. Plugin saves reference to passed in CallbackContext object.
3. Keep CallbackContext object reference, while returning results with setKeepCallback(true).
4. When the sequence is finished, return with setKeepCallback(false) (the default)

Then later...

1. Make another call to plugin.
2. Plugin overwrites saved CallbackContext reference, replace with passed in object.

Then steps 3-4 same as above.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Wow, there is a LOT of insight in this answer... maybe you should write the Cordova docs!

Comment: One thing I found out the hard way is that if you return false in the execute Method, there will be a result generated for you and you cannot return any more results. So always return true there then it works like a charm!
This can be another reason for the "second callback warning".

Comment: @Dunc - certainly *somebody* should try writing proper documentation for writing Cordova plugins.  Seriously.  The documentation is absurdly bad, at least on the Android side.  For example, it states that if you need to perform any initialization when the web view starts, you should implement `initialize(CordovaInterface, CordovaWebView)` ... but if you read the source, there's a comment there that states that plugins shouldn't really be doing this, but should implement `pluginInitialize()` instead.