# Cordova Android: how to listenen to custom events in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

with Cordova Android, how can javascript listen to custom event fired in Java code?

A typical use case is when an activity starts, it connects to a back end server and waits until the server sends back a message, then notifies javascript to make UI updates. How should it be done in Cordova?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at: [Asynchronous communication between Javascript and Phonegap Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177991/asynchronous-communication-between-javascript-and-phonegap-plugin)

This seems to be to be similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks Dustin, this is what I ended up doing - call a plugin from javascript and wait for the plugin to send back result when the server returns something.