# Using the sendJavascript() Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I know the question is highly general, and seem to be irrelevant. I myself know that this type of questions should not be asked here. But after researching for long, posting to the blogs of many Phonegap masters, I got no replies from them, I have now came to StackOverflow. So much so, that there are no documentation for this particular method anywhere on the Internet, neither in [PhoneGap Docs](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEgQjBAwAw&url=http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/&ei=g71oUrTFLYKzrge0-4HoAw&usg=AFQjCNFsaKE3BGtEls-lhoBfog6r8D-kQw&sig2=RUQSGWfiisWwZPOXqzqA9w&bvm=bv.55123115,d.bmk), nor in [Cordova Docs](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/&ei=rb1oUpfMCZGzrAe9j4HYAQ&usg=AFQjCNGO5QcxwwzB2nIQTSCapHJcIqUkBA&sig2=Gyy9MDsAL0UwZweoAYPf3A&bvm=bv.55123115,d.bmk).

My question is very simple. **I want to know, how to use the sendJavascript() in the** `DroidGap class` **or the** `Plugin class` **to call a function in Javascript**.

I found [this tutorial](http://www.jumpbyte.com/2012/phonegap-native-to-javascript/), but it is very obsolete and doesn't work with **Phonegap 3.0**. It would be very nice if someone suggest some modification in the tutorial, or some new approach.

*I don't need the code, just tell me how to do it. I just need a skeleton*

I posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177991/asynchronous-communication-between-javascript-and-phonegap-plugin), actually it is the original problem, to which I am looking the solution for.

Please suggest me something on this. I'll be very glad.

---

**Edit 1:**
On searching to the deepest of Google, I found this first documentation of this creepy method. [Here is the link](http://raphael-lemaire.com/phonegapjavadocs/com/phonegap/DroidGap.html#sendJavascript%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sendJavascript` function is defined in [CordovaWebView](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;a=blob_plain;f=framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java;hb=HEAD).

Each Cordova plugin has a `webView` property that should give you easy access to call the javascript function.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad for answering, but the question is when I write `sendJavacript()` and call some method of Javascript, where that method would reside (I mean in which JS file, if I am having many of them). I know the language I used is a bit vague, but please bear with me this time. Please ask if you wanna know anything else.

Comment: You should call the function as if you were in the global execution context

Comment: Sorry Vlad, I know about Android and Java, but I am very new to Web and Javascript. Please Please can you give me a detailed answer. As I said in the question, _I just need a skeleton not the full code_. Please help me.

Comment: Is as simple as this ```sendJavascript("alert('from native side');")```, just pass the javascript string that you want to execute

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I tried it, and its running. But then I need to call a Javascript function (say `callFromNative()`). So, where do I need to put that function in Javasrcript, I mean in which file, since there are so many Javascript files in the project. I know that feels odd, but please, I am waiting for to long.

Comment: It does not matter in which file you put it as long as you include the script in your index.html.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll now give it another shot. Fingers Crossed